# Преобразование числа в строку Java

Tags: java

```
char * utoa_builtin_div(uint32_t value, char *buffer)
{
   buffer += 11; 
// 11 байт достаточно для десятичного представления 32-х байтного числа
// и  завершающего нуля
   *--buffer = 0;
   do
   {
      *--buffer = value % 10 + '0';
      value /= 10;
   }
   while (value != 0);
   return buffer;
}
```

Прошерстил сайты и не особо понял, как этот алгоритм реализовать вручную на java. Вот нашел более менее простой способ через деление на 10.Но он не для java. Тут используются побитовые сдвиги. Как мне его написать на java?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: `String.valueOf(number)`

Comment: мне вручную надо, без toString,valueOf и подобных

Comment: Битовый сдвиг в java есть, остаток от деления, конкатенация строк циклы, деление тоже. Что вам ещё нужно для реализации?

Comment: Битовых сдвигов тут нет. Что конкретно вы не понимаете в представленом коде?

Comment: *--  ,это типо декремент ,но почему тогда после идет присваивание. и в джаве указателей нет.

Comment: В java есть передача по ссылке, что компенсирует отсутствие явных указателей, но в этой задаче они не нужны

Comment: @alexeykhodus В начале функции указатель помещается в конец строки. Потом декремент сдвигает указатель на позицию, в которую будет поставлена очередная цифра посредством присваивания. Цифры извлекаются и помещаются в строку в обратном порядке.

Comment: @Sergey понял,спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
String i2a(int value) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    do {
        int lastDigit = value % 10;
        sb.insert(0, lastDigit);
        value = value / 10;
    } while (value != 0);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

В java есть специальный тип для строк.
И удобные вспомогательные средства для работы с этими строками.
Одно из них `StringBuilder`
Извлекаем очередную цифру и вставляем в начало будущей строки.

Comment: Было бы проще сделать строку через `sb.append` и затем перевернуть её.

Comment: Возможно это так, учитывая как такие вещи обычно реализуются. Но с другой стороны языки типа java разве не должны быть подальше от железа и ближе к людям? Ведь естественно приписывать цифры спереди. Пусть компилятор оптимизирует.

Comment: Компилятор не сможет это оптимизировать. :(. А вообще игнорируйте моё замечание. Здесь всего десять символов, никто ничего не заметит.